# How to do multiple aggregated columns in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just to head off the quick-repliers, I'll mention that I'm not using MySQL so I can't use GROUP_CONCAT, and that I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-groupconcat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) already.

**The example**
(this is not the data i'm working with but it accurately describes my case)
Person table, with ID, Name columns
Person_CountriesVisited table, with PersonID, Country columns (1..M linking table)
Person_StatesVisited table, with PersonID, State columns (1..M linking table)

**The constraints**
I can't modify the DB. I can't modify much of the code, either, so this has to be done in SQL, not in code after running the query.

**The desired result**
A result set with the columns

Person.ID, 
Person.Name, 
[list of related Person_CountriesVisited.Country], 
[list of related Person_StatesVisited.State], 

which can also be filtered by a generic search term which applies across all columns.

**My attempts**

Now, my SQL-fu isn't all that sharp nowadays, but I'm doing what I can based on examples I've found.

1) I've tried using a scalar sub-query:

> SELECT P.ID, P.Name, 
>  ( select
>   CV.Country + ', '
>  FROM
>   Person_CountriesVisited CV ON P.ID =
>   CV.PersonId 
> FOR XML PATH ('')) AS
>   CountriesVisited,
>  ( SELECT
>   SV.State + ', '
>    FROM
>   Person_StatesVisited SV ON P.ID =
>   SV.PersonId 
> FOR XML PATH ('')) AS StatesVisited
>   FROM Person P
>  WHERE P.Name LIKE
>   '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
>  OR
>   CountriesVisited LIKE '%' +
>   @SearchTerm + '%'
>  OR StatesVisted
>   LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'

Which returns the data I want, but only when I remove the WHERE clause.   It doesn't work with the WHERE clause because SQL Server 2005 doesn't seem to like that i'm referencing a column created from a scalar subquery in the WHERE clause.   It's giving me an "Invalid column name 'CountriesVisited'" error (and again for the StatesVisited column).

2) I've tried the cross apply trick:

> SELECT P.ID, P.Name, CountriesVisited,
>   StatesVisited
>  FROM Person P
>   INNER JOIN Person_CountriesVisited CV ON
>   P.ID = CV.PersonID
>  CROSS APPLY
>   (
>  SELECT CV.Country + ', '
>   FROM Person P2 INNER JOIN
>   Person_CountriesVisited CV ON P2.ID =
>   CV.PersonID
>  WHERE P.ID =
>   P2.ID
>  FOR XML PATH ('')
>  )
>   PRE_TRIMMED (CountriesVisited)
>   
>   INNER JOIN Person_StatesVisited SV ON
>   P.ID = SV.PersonID
>   CROSS APPLY (
>  SELECT SV.State +
>   ', '
>  FROM Person P2 INNER JOIN
>   Person_StatesVisited SV ON P2.ID =
>   SV.PersonID FOR XML PATH ('')
>  )
>   PRE_TRIMMED (StatesVisited)
>  WHERE
>   P.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm +
>   '%'
>   OR CountriesVisited LIKE '%'
>   + @SearchTerm + '%'
>  OR StatesVisted LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm +
>   '%'

But that doesn't work either since you apparently can't have multiple pre_trimmed calls.

Anybody have suggestions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to alias your subqueries:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT P.ID
        ,P.Name
        ,( select CV.Country + ', '
         FROM Person_CountriesVisited CV ON P.ID = CV.PersonId 
         FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) AS CountriesVisited
        ,( SELECT SV.State + ', '
         FROM Person_StatesVisited SV ON P.ID = SV.PersonId 
         FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) AS StatesVisited
  FROM Person P
)
SELECT *
FROM X    
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
  OR CountriesVisited LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
  OR StatesVisted LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
```

You can do something similar in the second example.  Actually in the second example, just alias the second subquery as something new, like `PRE_TRIMMED2`.

Comment: BINGO! Thanks, I was hoping it'd be something simple.